# Plotting time series by year only in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a series that have dates in datetime format that look like:

```
2015-05-10  00:00:00
```

I would like to plot two different values in my dataframe over the same time periods and I've tried:

```
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(df['Date'].dt.year, df['Avg'], color='r')
plt.show()
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(df['Date'].dt.year, df['MW'], color='b')
plt.show()
```

But this gives me a strange format that can't even be dealt with by changing the ['Date'] column outside of plotting.

It plots as:

```
2015.0    2015.5   2016.0   2016.5.....etc
```

Tried changing to float form as well but to no avail.

All I want is one yearly tick over the entire series from 2015 to 2018 but when I convert to a string or integer I get something that looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`.set_xticks` is the most readable way to set the values you are seeing in the x axis, in my opinion.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data =[ {"Date":"2015-05-10", "Avg":34}, {"Date":"2016-05-10", "Avg":32}, 
        {"Date":"2017-05-10", "Avg":31}, {"Date":"2015-05-10", "Avg":31}, 
        {"Date":"2015-05-10", "Avg":26}, {"Date":"2015-05-10", "Avg":29}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(df['Date'].dt.year, df['Avg'], color='r')
ax.set_xticks([2015, 2016, 2017])

plt.show()
```

It also looks like you are having problems because you have multiple values for each year, so it plots the vertical lines you are seeing. An aggregate value, using pandas `.groupby` functions, appears to be what you want.

```
df["Year"] = df["Date"].dt.year

df = df.groupby("Year").mean().reset_index()

ax = plt.subplot(211)
ax.plot(df.Year, df['Avg'], color='r')
ax.set_xticks([2015, 2016, 2017])

plt.show()
```

Comment: I've already converted to datetime so why do it again? When I attempt this the same thing happens as above; the year shows on the x-axis but turns the continuous time series into a linear series that vertically peaks at each year.

Comment: I didn't know that you had already converted to datetime, I'll remove that and edit my post. I'm having trouble visualizing the problem you're talking about re: vertically peaking, could you post the plot as it appears now?

Comment: Posted the image above!

Comment: Editing my answer